# Android actions not showing up in actionbar

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio, android-appcompat

I have been trying to program a simple app for taking notes on android.
I want to have an "add" button showing in the actionbar of the main activity. However, it only shows up as an overflow. 
I tried

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:id="@+id/action_add"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_add"
    android:title="@string/add"
    android:showAsAction="always"></item>
</menu>
```

but I cannot run the app because android studio tells me

> should use app:showAsAction with the appcompat library with xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"

Any ideas? I am not, to my knowledge, using appcompat

Edit:
the java class:

```
public class NoteChoice extends Activity {
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.notechooser);
    SQLiteDatabase db = openOrCreateDatabase("Notes", MODE_PRIVATE, null);
    db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Notes ( id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, val VARCHAR )");


}
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu){
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.notechooser_actions, menu);
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}

public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item){
    switch(item.getItemId()){
        case R.id.action_add:
            onPause();
            startActivity(new Intent("com.example.theorangeutan.notes.Create"));
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

}

The styles.xml file:

```
<resources>

<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
</style>
<style name="splash" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light.NoActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
</style>
```

Comment: Post your styles file.

Comment: added it.  Apptheme is what is used in all Activities, splash is used for the splashscreen.

Answer (score 0):

`support-v7` is considered a 3rd party library, so XML attributes introduced via support-v7 must use the `app` namespace instead of `android` namespace so that backwards compatibility to v7 is guaranteed. For example, `android:showAsAction` is only available >= SDK 11, while `app:showAsAction` is available >= SDK 7.

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
<item android:id="@+id/action_add"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_add"
    android:title="@string/add"
    app:showAsAction="always"></item>
</menu>
```